# Wired connection loss

Tags: networking, 14.04, ethernet

When i started system wired connection works fine. But after a while suddenly i experience loss of ethernet connection and  able to establish the connection if and only if reboot the system. Is there any way to fix the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

find out your gateway ip (look at a  Gateway column for Destination 0.0.0.0 in `netstat -rn`) get the ping going to the gateway `ping GATEWAYIP` if pings are still going through when your experiencing ***loss*** it's not your PC